# BigDecimal division precision using string converted to BD

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am trying to convert string values into BigDecimal and then perform my calculation, but the output is not as expected. Please find the code below:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("320000");
        BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(0.1);
        BigDecimal b3 = new BigDecimal("9.6");

        BigDecimal b5 = new BigDecimal(320000);
        BigDecimal b6 = new BigDecimal(9.6);

        BigDecimal b4 = (
          b1.multiply(b2)
        ).multiply(
          b3.divide(b1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
        );
        System.out.println(b4.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

        BigDecimal b7 = (
          b5.multiply(b2)
        ).multiply(
          b6.divide(b5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
        );
        System.out.println(b7.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    }
}
```

The out is shown below for both the instances:

```
0.0000
0.9600
```

When I use the instantiate the numbers as BigDecimal rather than converting them from string in the second instance I am getting the desired output.

Can you please let me know why it is happening and how could I get the desired output of 0.9600 in the first instance.

Comment: Aren't those two totally different calculations?

Comment: Nope...they are the same calculation....In the first case I am converting string to BigDecimal and then performing the calculation....in the second case no conversion is happening before calculation

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487561/bigdecimal-add-strange-behavior) answer your question?

Comment: It might have something to do with "scale", as `new BigDecimal("9.6")` has a scale of 1, but `new BigDecimal(9.6)` has a scale of 49 (due to `9.6` actual being `9.5999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375`).

Comment: There is always a conversion. Either from a floating point literal or from a string. Using floating point gives unexpected results. It is gives more intuitive results to use string initializing.

Comment: Reduce your problem, because this is a bad question right now: the difference is not at the "final number", the difference already manifests after a single operation, so reduce your code to show _that_ and then ask about that. If, after reducing, you can't figure out why things are different. Because just because you write `9.6`, that doesn't mean the floating point number _is_ 9.6, because it's not. There is no true 9.6 in IEEE floats. `new BigDecimal("9.6")` is 9.6, `new BigDecimal(9.6)` _is not that value at all_.

Comment: Don't use `new BigDecimal(0.1)`. Use `new BigDecimal("0.1")`.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... Can you please let me know why it is happening and how could I get the desired output of 0.9600 in the first instance."*

For your division, remove the *RoundingMode* argument.

```java
b3.divide(b1)
```

When a *RoundingMode* is specified, the scale will be derived.

Here is the source code used internally by *BigDecimal*, for that method.
*[OpenJDK – GitHub – jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigDecimal.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigDecimal.java#L6021)*.

In your inner division, it will use a scale of 1, from *9.6*.

```java
b3.divide(b1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

So, this will return *0.0*, while the actual answer is *0.00003*.

As a note, if needed, you can specify the scale as the second parameter; *[BigDecimal#divide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal,int,java.math.RoundingMode))*.

```java
b3.divide(b1, 5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```